# How to fix error notice Array to String conversion

Tags: php

I have written this code for fetch data from MySQL Server. There is an error, how to fix it?

```
<?php 
$status=$_GET['status'];

if ($status=="disp") {

    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysqli_select_db($link,"mainstock");
    $res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM 1st_year");

    echo "<table>";

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";  echo $row=["id"];  echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";  echo $row=["BooksName"];  echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";  echo $row=["Avaibality"];  echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";  echo $row=["Price"];  echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";  echo $row=["Quantity"];  echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    };
    echo "</table>";

}
?>
```

Error in line 14, 15, 16, 17 which are

```
echo "<td>";  echo $row=["id"];  echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";  echo $row=["BooksName"];  echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";  echo $row=["Avaibality"];  echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";  echo $row=["Price"];  echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";  echo $row=["Quantity"];  echo "</td>";
```

Please help me!

Comment: _There is an error, how to fix it?_ What error? - Change `echo $row=["id"]; ` to `echo $row["id"]; `

Comment: What is error  should be what is not :) ?

Answer (score -1):

```
        echo "<td>". $row["id"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".  $row["BooksName"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>".  $row["Avaibality"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Price"]; . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".  $row["Quantity"]; . "</td>";
```

fix these lines like above

Comment: good answers have an explanation so the OP and future visitors can learn :)

Comment: this dont need any explnation some time you dont need to explain every tick

Comment: Just say what you changed that is it :) and you are right its hard to explain :)

Comment: @YahyaAyyoub not everything is obvious - why is this is a fix is what SO is looking for, the more complete your answer, the more people gain :)

Comment: @treyBake i'll try to improve my answers next time thanks for you'r advice :)

Comment: any time - @Imran